# Correct way to have a "setter" in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, setter, case-class

If in a Java class there is some logic or data-cleanup in the setter of a member, what is the correct and generally agreed upon approach to do the same for a Scala case-class?

Assertions? Implementing your own apply method?

Comment: Logic in getters and setters is a code smell in Java. Not to say no one's doing likewise in Scala, of course.

Comment: An analogous code smell in Scala is to have a mutable case class. You can use the copy() method to avoid that.

Comment: Don't use mutable state

Comment: @DonBranson I'd really like to avoid using a mutable state. The logic I'm referring to is more a validation & cleanup of the data that is going into that field.

Comment: That's my advice. mutability is a code smell, so avoid it. Just like validation logic in a setter is a code smell in Java and something you'd want to avoid. Use copy() to create a new object with the new value.

Comment: So, asking the "correct" way to put logic in a Java setter or make a mutable object in Scala is liking asking the "correct" way to roll through a stop sign. :)

Comment: @DonBranson got what you mean now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `def` or a `lazy val` for getting the transformed value. E.g.

```
case class PostalCode(value: String) {
  lazy val clean: String = value.replaceAll(" ","").toUpperCase
}
```

Another option, if you do not want the original value hanging around, and/or you want to throw an exception or otherwise fail for bad input:

```
case class PostalCode(value: String)
case object PostalCode {
  def parse(s: String): Option[PostalCode] = try {
    Some(PostalCode(someThrowingLogic(s)))
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }
  def clean(s: String): PostalCode = PostalCode(s.replaceAll(" ","").toUpperCase)
}
```

This leaves the user still able to use the normal constructor instead of `PostalCode.parse` or `PostalCode.clean`. Here is another option;

```
trait PostalCode {
  def value: String
}
case object PostalCode {
  private case class PCImpl(value: String) extends PostalCode
  def apply(v: String): PostalCode = v.replaceAll(" ","") match {
    case s if s.length == 6 =>
      PCImpl(s.toUpperCase)
    case _ =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(v + " is not a valid postal code.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose however that this still leaves value accessible from the outside. I'd like to get as close as possible to the setter behaviour, where I confirm if the value being set is valid or throw an exception.

Comment: I have added a couple of other options to my answer.